# direct event insert to attendees table exceotion if sdk versio lower than 19

Tags: android, calendar

I am building an application in which I am inserting events directly to the calendar plus I left the possibility to invite someone else and everything is perfectly fine if I execute it on android sdk version 19 and above, on lower versions I get an exception.
Here is the source:

```
       ContentResolver atend = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME, "Bajo");
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL, someonesEmail);
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP, CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE);
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE, CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_REQUIRED);
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED);
        val.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        Uri muri= atend.insert(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, val);
        Log.d("Atendees URI:",muri.toString());
        long Aeventid=Long.parseLong(muri.getLastPathSegment());
```

the Exception:

```
03-05 19:45:59.681    1255-1266/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLong(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:591)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLong(SQLiteSession.java:652)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong(SQLiteStatement.java:107)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:816)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:804)
            at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarDatabaseHelper.duplicateEvent(CalendarDatabaseHelper.java:3311)
            at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.insertInTransaction(CalendarProvider2.java:2265)
            at com.android.providers.calendar.SQLiteContentProvider.insert(SQLiteContentProvider.java:96)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:148)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-05 19:45:59.681    1632-1632/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-05 19:45:59.681    1632-1632/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2f7e288)
03-05 19:45:59.681    1632-1632/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:184)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:864)
            at com.example.rusev.vetcalendar.MainActivity.insertToCalendarImmunization(MainActivity.java:809)
            at com.example.rusev.vetcalendar.MainActivity.syncToCalendar(MainActivity.java:931)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you help me to identify what I miss?

Comment: What does the code you posted do? Are you just using it to insert data in database?

Comment: Yes I use it only to insert data in the Attendees table which results in sending an invitation to the someonesEmail.

Comment: Can anybody say what is wrong with the code I posted for older APIs but  still android 4.+ ?
This is taken from google: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html
and Attendees table the fields that I am should be available in API 14 +.